# Creating a function or loop to manipulate multiple variables simultaneously

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to generate modelled smoking prevalence based on current demographic, mortality and numbers of people being referred to and treated in quit support services in Wales.

To do this I want to manipulate data across rows and columns and generate a loop starting with a baseline population of smokers (17.2% of the adult population) which each successive year gets smaller as a result of people quitting (spontaneously or through services), dying from smoking-related diseases, with a small uplift each year from teenagers and adults starting smoking.

The population of smokers in any year = 
(Existing smoking population (previous year) + teenage starters (in last year) + adult starters (in last year) - (quitters (in last year) + deaths from smoking (in last year))

I have only been able to manipulate data in Excel and import in. I think I should be able to use lead() or a radix as the starting population but am not sure how to generate a function to loop across multiple columns/variables.

```
#Extract head of data frame
structure(list(Year = 2018:2023, Popn_15 = c(32526L, 33238L, 34162L, 
35419L, 35942L, 37310L), Popn_16_64 = c(1906559L, 1901378L, 
1898159L, 1895177L, 1892121L, 1888770L), Popn_65_over = c(658616L, 
669267L, 678630L, 688625L, 699857L, 711777L), Popn_16_over = c(2565175L, 
2570645L, 2576789L, 2583802L, 2591978L, 2600547L), start_15 = c(2927.34, 
2991.42, 3074.58, 3187.71, 3234.78, 3357.9), start_16 = c(38131.18, 
38027.56, 37963.18, 37903.54, 37842.42, 37775.4)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Popn_15", "Popn_16_64", "Popn_65_over", "Popn_16_over", "start_15", 
"start_16"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to produce a column of estimated smoking populations to then calculate prevalence proportions to visualise but cannot loop the data in R at present.

Many thanks in advance for any pointers or help.

Comment: You should be able to do this with `lag()` and `mutate()` from the dplyr package, but the data you provide does not seem to have info on quitters or deaths (apart from the missing starting population) so I can't really produce the code.

Comment: Thanks. Quitters = (smoking population * 0.031 [proportion currently accessing support] * 0.4 * 0.2 [attrition due to not all being successful and for long-term return to habit]) + (smoking population * 0.4 * 0.05).

Deaths = smoking population * 0.075 [estimated proportion of population who die each year from smoking-related cause]

Comment: Can you show what your expected output should look like for the data you have shared?

Comment: Output below - thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

This is the output expected which I have created by manually iterating the data manipulation by row (first calculating quitters and smoking deaths from previous year's smoking population then calculating using these figures the new smoking population)

```
dput(smok_projections)
structure(list(Year = 2018:2039, Popn_15 = c(32526L, 33238L, 
34162L, 35419L, 35942L, 37310L, 36706L, 37175L, 37900L, 37433L, 
36190L, 35291L, 35161L, 35226L, 35349L, 35472L, 35634L, 35801L, 
35955L, 36121L, 36190L, 36148L), Popn_16_64 = c(1906559L, 1901378L, 
1898159L, 1895177L, 1892121L, 1888770L, 1886206L, 1882590L, 1878168L, 
1873414L, 1868058L, 1860412L, 1852056L, 1844695L, 1837416L, 1831331L, 
1825159L, 1820966L, 1816035L, 1813212L, 1812904L, 1814767L), 
Popn_65_over = c(658616L, 669267L, 678630L, 688625L, 699857L, 
711777L, 724086L, 736654L, 750282L, 764671L, 778915L, 793895L, 
808374L, 821403L, 834068L, 845307L, 856400L, 865327L, 874819L, 
881993L, 886488L, 888608L), Popn_16_over = c(2565175L, 2570645L, 
2576789L, 2583802L, 2591978L, 2600547L, 2610292L, 2619244L, 
2628450L, 2638085L, 2646973L, 2654307L, 2660430L, 2666098L, 
2671484L, 2676638L, 2681559L, 2686293L, 2690854L, 2695205L, 
2699392L, 2703375L), start_15 = c(2927.34, 2991.42, 3074.58, 
3187.71, 3234.78, 3357.9, 3303.54, 3345.75, 3411, 3368.97, 
3257.1, 3176.19, 3164.49, 3170.34, 3181.41, 3192.48, 3207.06, 
3222.09, 3235.95, 3250.89, 3257.1, 3253.32), start_16 = c(38131.18, 
38027.56, 37963.18, 37903.54, 37842.42, 37775.4, 37724.12, 
37651.8, 37563.36, 37468.28, 37361.16, 37208.24, 37041.12, 
36893.9, 36748.32, 36626.62, 36503.18, 36419.32, 36320.7, 
36264.24, 36258.08, 36295.34), popn_smok = c(441210.1, 438922.3749356, 
436707.501004443, 434617.775035249, 432676.649893459, 430802.904211835, 
429060.975973056, 427276.931790465, 425531.406641874, 423828.370806947, 
422050.52577905, 420124.404578419, 418051.062251724, 415901.410828628, 
413721.712727943, 411522.988164282, 409332.175440519, 407151.360605936, 
405020.66961321, 402920.133702152, 400890.97455639, 398968.459862344
), hmq_ref_growth = c(0.0343, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 
0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 
0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0032, 
0.0032), hmq_prop_ref = c(0.0343, 0.0375, 0.0407, 0.0439, 
0.0471, 0.0503, 0.0535, 0.0567, 0.0599, 0.0631, 0.0663, 0.0695, 
0.0727, 0.0759, 0.0791, 0.0823, 0.0855, 0.0887, 0.0919, 0.0951, 
0.0983, 0.1015), hmq_quit = c(1210.6805144, 1316.7671248068, 
1421.91962327047, 1526.37762592379, 1630.32561679855, 1733.55088654842, 
1836.38097716468, 1938.12816260155, 2039.14650062786, 2139.48561583347, 
2238.55598873208, 2335.89168945601, 2431.38497805602, 2525.35336655143, 
2618.03099814242, 2709.46735407363, 2799.83208001315, 2889.14605485973, 
2977.71196299632, 3065.41637720597, 3152.60662391146, 3239.62389408223
), spont_quit = c(9044.80705, 8997.9086861798, 8952.50377059109, 
8909.6643882226, 8869.8713228159, 8831.45953634261, 8795.75000744765, 
8759.17710170452, 8723.39383615841, 8688.48160154241, 8652.03577847052, 
8612.55029385758, 8570.04677616033, 8525.97892198687, 8481.29511092282, 
8436.22125736777, 8391.30959653064, 8346.6028924217, 8302.9237270708, 
8259.86274089412, 8218.264978406, 8178.85342717805), deaths_smok = c(33090.7575, 
32919.17812017, 32753.0625753333, 32596.3331276436, 32450.7487420094, 
32310.2178158876, 32179.5731979792, 32045.7698842848, 31914.8554981405, 
31787.127810521, 31653.7894334287, 31509.3303433814, 31353.8296688793, 
31192.6058121471, 31029.1284545957, 30864.2241123211, 30699.9131580389, 
30536.3520454452, 30376.5502209907, 30219.0100276614, 30066.8230917293, 
29922.6344896758)), .Names = c("Year", "Popn_15", "Popn_16_64", 
"Popn_65_over", "Popn_16_over", "start_15", "start_16", "popn_smok", 
"hmq_ref_growth", "hmq_prop_ref", "hmq_quit", "spont_quit", "deaths_smok"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```